# Can't use derived attribute @sum on other derived attribute @count

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data, derived

There is [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsderivedattributedescription) about this new feature. It is said:

> Supported functions include @count and @sum.

I have three entities: `Session`, `Button` and `Click`. One `session` linked to many `buttons`, one `button` linked to many `clicks`. The goal is to save all the clicks on every button I have on the screen. `Click` have attributes `x` and `y`. 
I can have several sessions, listed in a View to choose. When I tap the session, I will load all saved clicks and continue clicking. So, I want to show user how many clicks he did in that session in the list. I tried to make derived attribute `buttons.clickCount` of `Button` entity with key path `clicks.@count`. it works fine. But if I try to create derived attribute of `Session` to sum all the clicks of all the buttons - I got stuck. 
`buttons.clickCount.@sum` does not compile. The error is

> ... error: Misconfigured Property: Session.clickCount key path
>   “buttons.clickCount.@sum” references a derived attribute

Next try is `buttons.clicks.@count`. It compiles well, but the app crashes in runtime with error

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unsupported: (unsupported
>   function)'

Is there a way to use derived attributes to count entities with two level link without creating special FetchRequest for that purpose?

Comment: The error message tells you that you can't create a derived attribute from another derived attribute so to me it looks like you need another solution. Not sure about the second error but it looks like chaining two relationships doesn't work either.

Comment: yes, I'm using another FetchRequest to count it right now. Just wander in this new feature if I'm doing something wrong. I'm newbie in Swift.

Comment: Have you been able to use the @sum function? I have the following error when I use a derived attribute to sum amounts of expenses “expenses.amount.@sum” *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'currently unsupported (unsupported function on to many (not count or sum))'. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64750427/2681506