# Core Data Derived Attributes with a sum function

Tags: ios, sql, core-data, derived-attribute

I have two entities in my app: `User` & `Expense`. A user has many expenses. Expense as an attribute `amount` (of type Int32).

I added a derived attribute `expensesCount` (of type Int16) on the user to count the number of expenses, using the derivation `expenses.@count`. It's working fine, the app compiles, launches, and when I save a relationship, the value for the expensesCount attribute is updated.

I also added a derived attribute `expensesAmount` on the user to count the total amount of all related expenses. I use the derivation `expenses.amount.@sum`. The app compiles but crash at launch with the following error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'currently unsupported (unsupported function on to many (not count or sum))'
```

Any idea why?

PS: I also tried another syntax recommended on Twitter `sum:(expenses.amount)`, but I got the same crash: https://twitter.com/numist/status/1181686971892031488?s=21

Comment: I tried a test project with the same relationships and derived attributes, and it works. I'm not sure why it wouldn't work for you-- maybe something with the version of iOS you're running the code on? I'm trying it with iOS 14.0. Or maybe something with the attribute type for `amount`? I tried `Double`.

Comment: Thanks @Tom. I'm running iOS 14.2 & using Xcode 12.2. Here is an example project I sent to Apple Feedback Assistant: https://gofile.io/d/5U2Caj. From my understanding, it's only possible to use the ```@sum``` function for one to many relationships, and not many to many. In my example project, you'll see that the derived attribute is using a many to many relationship. Let me know if you reproduce the bug on your side (can be a bug, a feature improvement, a bad error message...).

Comment: I see. From your question it sounded like you had a one-to-many relationship, not many-to-many. That seems to be the reason, unfortunately. If you can't switch to one-to-many then you're probably out of luck with this technique until Apple fixes the framework.

Comment: When I asked the question, I was not able to have the @sum function work at all. I tried various things until it worked, and I discovered it was probably due to the type of relationship involved. It’s still an hypothesis but I hope the Apple feedback will be checked.